# Not able to pass data between activities in kotlin in android

Tags: android, kotlin

**First screen I am passing data as:**

```
 /** Start Events Schedule screen **/
    private fun startEventScheduleForTodaysEvents(eventCode: String?) {
        val eventsIntent = Intent(this, ActEventSchedule::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(Keys.EVENT_CODE,"data")
        startActivity(eventsIntent)
    }
```

**Second Screen I am receiving data as:**

```
/** Get data from previous screen **/
    private fun getDataFromPrevScreen() {

        val extras = intent.extras
        if (extras != null) {
            eventCode = extras.getString(Keys.EVENT_CODE)
        }

    }
```

**I am not able to receive the data**

[image]

### {EDIT}

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.act_event_schedule)
        //Get data from previous screen
        getDataFromPrevScreen()
    }
```

Comment: in `OnCreate` after setting the content in second screen

Comment: @NileshRathod .. I shared it

Answer (score 0):

You are passing one intent and adding data to different intent

```
 val eventsIntent = Intent(this, ActEventSchedule::class.java)
 intent.putExtra(Keys.EVENT_CODE,"data")              // You are adding data to intent
 startActivity(eventsIntent)          // you are passing events Intent
```

Your code should be as below

```
val eventsIntent = Intent(this, ActEventSchedule::class.java)
eventsIntent.putExtra(Keys.EVENT_CODE,"data")
startActivity(eventsIntent)
```